# WSO2 Identity Server - dashboard timeout

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a recent installation of wso2 Identity Server 5.7.0 with a Citrix Netscaler load balancer as a front end. Single Sign On is working well, but the Dashboard eventually times out and I get

> "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error."

Nothing is recorded in the log until the timeout is reached and then I receive

> "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"

Not sure where to look next.

[Screen shot of resulting UI message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmHT8.png)

Log Trace:

```
==> wso2carbon.log <==
[2020-02-17 06:49:18,146]  WARN -  Could not lock System prefs. Unix error code 0. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}
[2020-02-17 06:49:18,146]  WARN -  Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}
[2020-02-17 06:49:48,145]  WARN -  Could not lock System prefs. Unix error code 0. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}
[2020-02-17 06:49:48,145]  WARN -  Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}
[2020-02-17 06:50:12,072]  INFO -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/services/SAML2SSOAuthenticationService] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:193)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:704)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
        at org.jaggeryjs.modules.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:379)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_call_1(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:27)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnXML_3(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:67)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnJSON_4(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:82)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1._c_login_1(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag:17)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1.call(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6._c_script_0(/dashboard//acs.jag:67)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.call(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.call(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.exec(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-02-17 06:50:12,076] ERROR -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: connect timed out (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#27)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_call_1(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:27)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnXML_3(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:67)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnJSON_4(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:82)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1._c_login_1(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag:17)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1.call(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6._c_script_0(/dashboard//acs.jag:67)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.call(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.call(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.exec(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: connect timed out
        at org.jaggeryjs.modules.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:404)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: connect timed out
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:203)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:81)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
        at org.jaggeryjs.modules.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:379)
        ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:193)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:704)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
        ... 84 more
 {JAGGERY.acs:jag}
[2020-02-17 06:50:12,077] ERROR -  org.mozilla.javascript.JavaScriptException: JavaException: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: connect timed out (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#76) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.JavaScriptException: JavaException: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: connect timed out (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#76)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.JavaScriptException: JavaException: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: connect timed out (/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag#76)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnXML_3(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:76)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnJSON_4(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag:82)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.c0.call(/dashboard/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1._c_login_1(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag:17)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.controllers.login_logout.c1.call(/dashboard/controllers/login-logout/SAML2SSOAuthenticationClient.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6._c_script_0(/dashboard//acs.jag:67)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.call(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.call(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.dashboard.c6.exec(/dashboard//acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        ... 49 more

==> http_access_2020-02-17.log <==
10.91.0.12 - - [17/Feb/2020:06:50:12 -0600] "POST /dashboard/acs HTTP/1.1" 500 786 "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/samlsso" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"

==> localhost_access_log2020-02-17.log <==
Mon 2/17/2020 @ 06:50:12.81 AM CST 10.91.0.12 (-) > 10.91.0.2:443 "POST /dashboard/acs HTTP/1.1" - 60086 500 786 http-nio-9443-exec-34 "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/samlsso" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" - - -
```

Comment: What is "Apache 8"?

Comment: Sorry, I edited out the Apache 8.

Comment: Is this the issue you are facing  https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7011

Comment: Is this IdentityServer node fronted with any Load balancer? Can you please attach the screenshot of the error in UI and also the console logs?

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga, My symptoms is similar but, I do not receive an unauthorized access message.

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah, screen shot of UI and log trace added.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related to the wso2is server residing behind a load balancer and a firewall block. The wso2is server (private IP) is making a call to it's public name (public IP), but needed a firewall rule allowance to do so. Once a rule was added, the dashboard works successfully.